# How to transfer imageview into a ListView on a different layout?

Tags: java, android

I have a layout with a heart imageview to "favorite" the image. When the heart is clicked I want the image to go into another layout. I am trying to accomplish something like a music application. When user favorites a song it goes into another layout under Favorites. I am trying to accomplish the same something but with an image and some text. Whats the best way to accomplish this? Thank You!

ClassOne.java

```
private ImageView favHeartImage;

LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ClassTwo, null);
favListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_view);

favHeartImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           //add the image into ClassTwo listview
        }
    });
```

ClassTwo.xml

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/list_view" />
```

Comment: how do you populate that listview?

Comment: it doesnt have to be a listview. I just want to have a small imageview and same text going down a list

Comment: so when favHeartImage is clicked save the text in a list and send it to the other activity via intent . in that activity just retrieve the intent values and display them the same way you did on the first activity

Comment: If ClassOne and ClassTwo are on the same activity when favHeartImage is clicked save the data in a list that you will use to populate classTwo Listview and just call notyfydatasetchange on that listview

Comment: Thank you steveen! i got it to work!